# Clustering for mixed type of 2D data in R

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis, k-means, dbscan

I have two data sets, A and B. Each data sets contain multiple coordinates of points.

Now I want to perform a cluster analysis for these two data sets.
I know there is plenty of clustering methods for 2D data, like hdbscan from R package 'largeVis', and also k-means and dbscan algorithms. And I also know that 'gower' distance can be used for mixed 1d data frames.

However, are there any kinds of algorithms for mixed 2d data? I am looking for a R solution but also open to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think Gower is restricted to 1d dataframes?

What is a "mixed 1d" dataframe anyway? How can a single attribute be mixed?

Most clustering algorithms will work okay in higher dimensional data. Just at some point your distance functions break down due to the curse of dimensionality.

Comment: By mentioning the 1d data I mean the data frame is simple mix of 1 data, for example: age, sex, salary... etc

Comment: However, by mentioning the 2d data, I am refering to the coordinates, since x and y coordinates make up one point.

Comment: Generalized DBSCAN could easily be used with two distance measures. Or you just define your own distance that combines, e.g., Haversine on the coordinates and Gower on categorical data. But you'll have to choose weights somehow.

Comment: Hi Anony, thank you for your comments. Is there any example that use DBSCAN and applied to coordinates data?

Comment: Yes, everywhere. It's the most common use case.

Comment: Yes,  but seems not for mixed coordinate data